# How to parse a web page from a local javascript file

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-app

I need to parse a content that is dynamically generated by a javascript from a remote page.

For example, I need to get the price from this page: http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/BRG-Newest-Fashional-Protective-Case-For_1666645206.html#J-wrapper

but the price is generated by a javascript, so when I download the page with ajax, it downloads only the html file without the results of the scripts.

So I tried to embed in the background an iframe and then parse the document inside this iframe, but there is a security issue that doesn't let me parse it.

Do you know if there is another way I can do it?

The function that I use is this:

```
 $.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: 'text',
      success: function(html, _, xhr) {});
```

but the resulting HTML is without the scripts information, so the price is empty.

I tried to use also:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>contents demo</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<iframe src="http://api.jquery.com/" width="80%" height="600" id="frameDemo"></iframe>

<script>
document.getElementById("frameDemo").onload = function() {
var contents = $( "#frameDemo" ).contents();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

but I get this error:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement':
Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "api.jquery.com".  
The frame requesting access has a protocol of "file", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". 
Protocols must match.
```

Comment: your question is not getting

Comment: do this serverside to prevent same-domain origin policy

Comment: I need to do it client side, so I get the same-domain policy, is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an iframe, try using a chrome app webview. It will run in a segregated container without the restrictions you referenced. But you can still communicate with it.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that, I will try it right now and let you know if it works, thanks a lot!

Comment: It looks like, the webview works just within a Chrome App and not in a sigle html file. I will explore this possibility but I am still looking for a way to do it from an html if it can be done.

Comment: just for reference here is the link of the webview: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview

Comment: ah yeah, sorry. bad manners to not include a link, but I plead mobile phone submission degradation.